# How to calculate CRC checksum in Actionscript 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, checksum, crc

I am developing an application in flex in which I need to calculate checksum of different files. I would like to know if there is a direct method in actionscript to calculate that or do I have to go for any external libraries?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're satisfied with an answer, please start off your Stack Overflow experience right and mark something as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

[as3corelib](http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/) maintained by Mike Chambers/Adobe, contains everything you probably need in its [crypto section](http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/crypto/) including:

- HMAC
- MD5
- MD5Stream
- SHA1
- SHA224
- SHA256
- WSSEUsernameTocken

Comment: Thanks Tegeril. Here I am assuming that there are two parts. First, get the contents of the file in one shot. Then calculate MD5 of it. So, for the second part the above answer is very much useful. But at the firt part, I am unable to get the contents of the file in one-shot.

Answer (score 1):

how do you use this as3corelib to perform a md5 on a file i.e. "c:\documents and settings\all user\desktop\demofile.xml" in php and c# you can md5files and get the checksum of the file - i also use md5summer to see if the outputted md5 is correct php and visual c# output the correct md5 however i cant find any easy tut that explains how to do this using flex / air / as3 nothing - i have imported the followinng libs.

import com.adobe.crypto.HMAC;
            import com.adobe.crypto.MD5;
            import com.adobe.crypto.SHA1;
            import com.adobe.crypto.SHA224;
            import com.adobe.crypto.SHA256;
            import com.adobe.crypto.MD5Stream;

i would have though that it would be md5stream be googling this turns up nought - please any help on how to do a simple md5 checksum of a local file would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this script.  I think it will do what you have in mind:

http://code.google.com/p/queueloader-as3/source/browse/trunk/build/src/nochump/util/zip/CRC32.as?r=57